# How to log the URL scheme (http or https) in Jetty request log?

Tags: logging, jetty, jetty-10

How can I include the URL request scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) in Jetty 10 request log?  Something similar with what [can be done in Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/359476/how-to-log-the-url-scheme-http-https-in-apache) but for Jetty.

I am using this setting:

```
jetty.requestlog.formatString='%{client}a - %u %t "%r" %s %O "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %{server}a'
```

which is basically a standard log plus the requested domain at the end.  I would like to add `http://` or `https://` to the requested domain.

Answer (score 2):

The `scheme` of a request is not present on an HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 request.

In HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 that scheme is present as the `:scheme` pseudo-header on all requests.

The scheme in Jetty could be any of the supported schemes that the Connectors support (eg: "fcgi", "http", "https", "ws", "wss", etc).

In practice the scheme comes from the request authority.

In HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 the scheme is determined by a combination of Connector security settings and Forwarding headers, if the request is secure, then the scheme is `https`, otherwise it is `http` (unless overridden by Forwarding headers to be something else).

On HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 the scheme is built into the low level protocol, but can be overridden by the [`Forwarded` RFC7239 headers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7239).

There is no provision in `CustomRequestLog` to write the authority or scheme currently.

So I opened an enhancement request for it
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/9980